# Google Earth Engine ee.Number to integer

Tags: javascript, integer, google-earth-engine

This is probably a simple question for people familiarized with the Code Editor of Google Earth Engine (https://code.earthengine.google.com/) or generally Javascript.

In my code, I need to use the size of an object for a boolean conditional (e.g. n>0). However, the output of .size() which I would store in n does not return a plain integer, but a ee.Number structure and I am not being able to transform it into an integer to properly evaluate the conditional.

Example with the structure ee.Number of Earth Engine:

```
var n=ee.Number(1)
print(n)
print(n.int())
print(n==1)
print(n===1)
print(n.int()==1)
print(n.int()===1)
print(n.int()== parseInt(1))
```

This outputs these evaluate as false, even when I try to tast the number structure into an int.

```
1
1
false
false
false
false
false
```

note:

```
print(typeof n)
```

returns an object (JSON):

```
object
```

Any help very much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to how GEE works. Processing steps are constructed locally as objects and then only evaluated by the server once another function requires it.

`print` is one of the functions that requires execution, this is why it shows as integer in your console.

You can force evaluation with `.getInfo()`... this however should be used with caution, because everything is pulled to the client side, which can be problematic with big objects.

So this works:

```js
var n=ee.Number(1)

print(n)
print(n.getInfo()==1)
```

giving

> 1
>   true

[This](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/concepts_overview) section of the documentation explains the background.

Answer (score 0):

If the value of n indeed is JSON, try to parse it:

```
n = JSON.parse(n);
```

Then convert it into an integer:

```
n = parseInt(n);
```

Comment: I tried this potential solution but did not work. Maybe I am missing something.